# What is the best way to lazy load angular module(Segment.com) based on data (API key) from HTTP call?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to instantiate segment angular module based on the api key I recieve from http call

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

// Import the Segment module
import { SegmentModule } from 'ngx-segment-analytics';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  AppComponent
],
imports: [
BrowserModule,
   // Segment Importation
   SegmentModule.forRoot({ apiKey: 'YOUR_WRITE_APIKEY', debug: true, loadOnInitialization: true 
  })
],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I am trying to get the `'YOUR_WRITE_APIKEY',` from the service. What is the best way to get the data and provide it to the module?

Comment: what do you mean load-based/provide-data-to they are two different  things

Comment: I want to replace the apiKey with a value I receive from an AJAX call which is inside service.